# How to display only issues that would not be closed by a "Fix #123" commit message once merged into the default branch?

Tags: github

It's simple to display open/close issues on Github :
[image: issue : Is open or closed]

When you make a commit to solve an issue, you can reference the issue in the commit name with for example `closes #4`, `close #4`, `fixes #4`,  `fix #4`, etc.

Once the commit is pushed, the issues is closed.
BUT, if you're working in a **different branch than the default one** (usually master) a message will appear into the issue instead of closing it. This message says that the issue will close once commit is merged into master.

[image: referenced commit into issue]

Is there a way to search for issues that are not tagged to be close when the commit get merged ?
For example something like : `is:issue is:notTaggedAsClosed` ?

It would help me a lot to find the issues I need to look at before everything gets merged to master !

Thanks

Comment: I'm just guessing here but could you please also try `is:issue state:closed` instead of `is:issue is:closed`. I'm not sure if it'll help though, it's just a guess.

Comment: Nice try @GökayGürcan ! But it's not working `No results matched your search.`

Comment: Sorry about that. I wish that would work. You can see more usages in [here](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/), maybe one of them helps.

Comment: I've read this page before I posted, no luck either.

Comment: I sent a mail to github team and started an issue in this repo : https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/542

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible.

I contacted github staff and here's their answer :

> This is not possible currently. Thanks for the suggestion though! I have added it to our list for our team to consider.

I also opened an issue on this repo : https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/542

I'll edit the answer if it changes some day.